# Does a bounded sequence in $C^k$ have a convergent subsequence in $C^{k-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact, let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\{f_n\} \subset C^k(K)$ be a bounded sequence w.r.t $C^k$ norm. Does it have a convergent subsequence in $C^{k-1}(K)$. If so how can one prove this?

Comment: Maybe one can apply Arzela Ascoli on several stages, starting from the last derivative, and using equicontinuity  on $\{f_n^{(k-1)}(x)\}$

Comment: what is the $C^k$ norm ??? I never saw that. do you mean $L^p$ or $H^{k,p}$ or $C^{k,p}$ or ... ??? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition

Comment: Hi, consider upvoting the answers to your previous questions and possibly the answer below, if it helps you. I see that you haven't voted anything till now. In this way MSE users may not be willing to answer your next questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

The proof here, works for $K=[a,b]\subset \mathbb R^1$, but I think it can be modified for $K\subset \mathbb R^n$, because Arzela-Ascoli theorem can be generalized for any metric compact space $K$.

Let us denote with $|.|_\infty$ the supremum norm in $C^0(K)$.
You have that $\{f_n^{(k-1)}\}$ is equicontinuous, since $\{f_n^{(k)}\}$ is uniformly bounded: $|f_n|_{C^k}\leq M$, then by Arzela Ascoli it has a uniformly convergent subsequence (in the $C^{k-1}$ seminorm): $ |f_n^{(k-1)}-g_{k-1}|_\infty\to 0$. Here $g_{k-1}$ is the limit function. Then from this subsequence, you chose another subsequence $\{f_s^{(k-2)}\}$ such that $|f_s^{(k-2)}-g_{k-2}|_\infty\to 0$, since it is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous. Here we use that since $\{f_s^{(k-1)}\}$ is uniformly bounded, then $\{f_s^{(k-2)}\}$ is equicontinuous. We continue choosing subsequences the same way to finally get that $|f_s^{(0)}-g_0|_\infty\to 0$. For the final subsequence, call it $\{f_n\}$ you have that $|f_n-g_0|_\infty\to 0,\,|f_n^{(1)}-g_1|_\infty\to 0,...\, |f_n^{(k-1)}-g_{k-1}|_\infty\to 0$. It is clear that $f^{(l)}(x)=g_l(x),\,l=1,2,...,k-1$ and that $|f_n-f|_{C^{k-1}}\to 0$, where $f:=g_0$.

Why $\{f_n^{(k-1)}\}$ is equicontinuous ?
$$|f_n^{(k-1)}(x)-f_n^{(k-1)}(y)|=|f_n^{(k)}(\xi)(x-y)|\leq M|x-y|\leq \epsilon,\,\,\forall x,y\in K:\,|x-y|\leq \epsilon/M,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$$. Here $M$ is the constant which bounds the sequence, i.e $|f_n|_{C^k}\leq M,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$.